# Sorting conversation array by author in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a very long txt file with a conversation in the following format:

```
[19/12/17 16:30:36] A: ‎Los mensajes en este grupo ahora están protegidos con cifrado de extremo a extremo.
[19/12/17 16:31:23] B: Buenas tardes, bienvenidos
‎[19/12/17 16:31:36] B: ‎imagen omitida
[19/12/17 16:31:36] C: Hola!! ☺
[19/12/17 16:31:51] D: Hola!!!!
[19/12/17 16:32:10] B: Estamos aquí reunidos... bueno, todos sabéis ya para qué
[19/12/17 16:32:49] B: Formamos parte de un estudio de x relacionadas con la Lógica Convergente 
[19/12/17 16:34:32] E. Carvajal: Hola...!
[19/12/17 16:34:37] B: Antes de nada,(...) “lista de espera”
[19/12/17 16:37:23] C: Hola❗❗❗
[19/12/17 16:38:17] F: Por cierto como no os conozco a todos yo soy e ‍♀
[19/12/17 16:39:19] G: Soy soy x‍♂
[19/12/17 16:39:51] B: Yo x
```

I have already split the txt file into an array using `split("[")`. 
I'm using `[` as the messages are long and contain linebreaks. All `[` signs that are not part of timestamp are escaped.

As of now, this gives me an array of messages like so:

```
1: "[timestamp] b: blabla"
2: "[timestamp] c: blabla"
3: "[timestamp] a: blabla"
(...)
3000: "[timestamp] b: blabla"
```

Now I would need to save the items in the array into different arrays based on author, probably looping through it and identifying unique authors, **being unique author the text between ] and :** in every item.

The end result should be a collection of arrays in which every one contains a collection of messages by author:

```
[timestamp] c: blabla
[timestamp] c: blabla
[timestamp] c: blabla
```

Then:

```
[timestamp] b: blabla
[timestamp] b: blabla
```

And so on.

I imagine I could iterate on the array and identify all the unique `"] author:"` and then push them into their own array, but I'm a bit lost on how to do about doing just that.

I remember doing something similar with Lodash back in the day, but I can't remember the name of the function. How would you go about something like this in JS?

Comment: Splittitng on `[` seems like a bad idea. What if a message contains one? Unless they're encoded in some way. Also please share your attempts.

Comment: Can you show us a little more clearly on the output

Comment: Is that your final result, or is there more following it, like extracting the timestamp and the string literal, ...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that each line is turned into an object structure, so you get objects like:

```
{ timestamp: "2019-01-01T12:13:44", author: "Helen", msg: "blablabla" }
```

You could sift through the lines using a `Map` to collect the records by their author.

```js
// Sample input:
const text = `[2019-01-02T12:03:08] john peterson: blabla
[2019-01-02T16:33:15] helen bloom: blabla
[2019-01-02T17:00:10] mark stanley: blabla
[2019-01-02T17:14:44] helen bloom: blabla
[2019-01-02T17:14:59] mark stanley: blabla
[2019-01-02T17:22:21] jenifer mcenroe: blabla`;

// Parse/structure the data:
const data = text
    .match(/.+/g) // Split into lines
    .map(line => line.match(/\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*?)\:\s*(.*)/)) // Pattern match
    .filter(Boolean) // Exclude non-matching lines
    // ... and structure into objects:
    .map(([, timestamp, author, msg]) => ({timestamp, author, msg}));     
// Create an array per author using a Map
const map = new Map(data.map(({author}) => [author, []]));
// Populate those arrays 
data.forEach(item => map.get(item.author).push(item)); 
// ...and extract them into the final result:
const result = Array.from(map.values()); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I really like your solution but is failing (only one object created), I think its because the line split, as given the length and complexity of my file Id rather split the lines at ´[´.

Comment: The crucial factor is not the line split, but the regular expression that works on one line: `/\[(.*?)\]\s+(.+?)\:\s+"(.*)"/`. If a line does not match this pattern, it is rejected.

Comment: Anyway, I would be interested to see the first 10 lines of your data, as even there it should be possible to see why those 10 (or 9) did not pass the pattern match.

Comment: Oh wait, I see you changed the data in the question. So then leave out the quotes in the regular expression as well.

Comment: I added real data in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

this might help, `Object.entries(result)` would give you a pair `[author, messages]` while `Object.values` would only give you messages

```js
const groupByAuthor = src => src
  .split('\n')
  .reduce((res, row) => {
    const [, author] = /\] (\w):/.exec(row) || [];
    
    if (author) {
      res[author] = (res[author] || []).concat(row);
    }
    
    return res;
  }, {})
;


const source = `
[timestamp] a: "blabla 1"
[timestamp] b: "blabla 2"
[timestamp] c: "blabla 3"
[timestamp] b: "blabla 2"
[timestamp] c: "blabla 3"
[timestamp] d: "blabla 4"
`

const result = groupByAuthor(source);

console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't split by '/n', as the txt is complex and contains line breaks in multiple places aside from at the end of each msg... Please see edit.

Comment: provide a real*ish* example of your data

Answer (score 0):

Or simply thus

```
const msgByAuthor = (messages, author) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('(.+)\\s'+ author +':(.*)', "gm");
  return messages.match(regex);
}

const messages = `Put messages here`;
console.log(msgByAuthor(messages, 'C'));

// Array ["[19/12/17 16:31:36] C: Hola!! ☺", "[19/12/17 16:37:23] C: Hola❗❗❗"]
```